# How do I append a column in a dataframe and and give each unique string a number?

Tags: python

I'm looking to append a column in a pandas data frame that is similar to the following "Identifier" column:

```
Name.                Age                     Identifier
Peter Pan            13                      PanPe
James Jones          24                      JonesJa
Peter Pan            22                      PanPe
Chris Smith          19                      SmithCh
```

I need the "Identifier" column to look like:

```
Identifier
PanPe01
JonesJa01
PanPe02
SmithCh01
```

How would I number each original string with 01? And if there are duplicates (for example Peter Pan), then the following duplicate strings (after the original 01) will have 02, 03, and so forth?

I've been referred to the following theory:

```
combo="PanPe"
Counts={}
if combo in counts:
   count=counts[combo]
   counts[combo]=count+1
else:
   counts[combo]=1
```

However, getting a good example of code would be ideal, as I am relatively new to Python, and would love to know the syntax as how to implement an entire column iterated through this process, instead of just one string as shown above with "PanPe".

Comment: You have an  ​​Identifier column and you want a new column next to it ? or will it be created from the name column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)** here:

```
df['new_Identifier']=df['Identifier'] + (df.groupby('Identifier').cumcount() + 1).astype(str).str.pad(2, 'left', '0')  #thanks @dm2 for the str.pad part
```

**Output**:

```
          Name  Age Identifier new_Identifier
0    Peter Pan   13      PanPe        PanPe01
1  James Jones   24    JonesJa      JonesJa01
2    Peter Pan   22      PanPe        PanPe02
3  Chris Smith   19    SmithCh      SmithCh01
```

Comment: For the required result you could also left pad the count with 0 `.str.pad(2, 'left', '0')`

Comment: I forgot this, Thank  you @dm2

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumcount here:

```
df['new_Identifier']=df['Identifier'] + (df.groupby('Identifier').cumcount() + 1).astype(str).str.pad(2, 'left', '0')  #thanks @dm2 for the str.pad part

      Name         Age    Identifier   new_Identifier
0    Peter Pan     13     PanPe        PanPe01
1    James Jones   24     JonesJa      JonesJa01
2    Peter Pan     22     PanPe        PanPe02
3    Chris Smith   19     SmithCh      SmithCh01
```

Thank you @dm2 and @Bushmaster

Comment: FYI, if the answer by @Bushmaster answered your question, it would be better to upvote and accept it as the correct answer. This is the best way to a) thank the person answering and b) show other people which answer was useful for your case.